# "Device management downloading" notification: why and how to get rid of it?

Tags: updates, notifications

I see "Device management downloading" notification. It appeared when I was not using the phone: why did it appear and how can I prevent it from appearing again? I don't want to update my phone's OS.

[image]

I use a rooted Samsung Galaxy SIII with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: You can find out what app is responsible by long-tapping the notification and choosing **App info**. When you've done that, [edit] your question.

Comment: Yep what dan said is true, otherwise we have no idea. Why not update your firmware if there is a newer official release? Security is important, as is stability in updates!

Comment: @RossC sometimes best to avoid.

Comment: Have you considered that this might be a Mobile Device Management being driven by Corporate/ IT from your place of work? This smells of MDM and I cant be sure which one given the limited info so far.

Comment: That's a personal phone which I have never used for my work.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Google also has in built device management feature. Maybe it's that. Check it. Did you try the above comment suggestions?